# Registering a shared service with a custom factory

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, di, factory

I'm wondering how (if I can) register a shared service with a custom factory.

Consider the following code:

```
class MyApiFactory {
    private $config;

    public function ___construct(Config $config) {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    //this method could either be __invoke
    //or the class could implement some factory interface
    public function create() {
        return new MyApi($this->config->get('some-value'), $this->config->get('some-other-value'));
    }

}

class MyApi {
}

class MyService1 {
    public function __construct(MyApi $api) {}
}

class MyService2 {
    public function __construct(MyApi $api) {}
}
```

With other PHP DI frameworks - I would register `MyApiFactory` as a factory for `MyApi`. If I requested for service `MyService1` the DI container would see that It needs `MyApi` and therefore execute `MyApiFactory` to get `MyApi` - `MyApi` would then be stored as a service (if the container supports sharing).

Then I ask for `MyService2` which also needs `MyApi` - as `MyApi` has already been created before - it just pulls it from the DI container and injects it in `MyService2`.

Therefore `MyApi` in `MyService1` & `MyService2` are the same.

I can't seem to find a way to do this in Magento 2. Basically I want to avoid creating `MyApi` twice.

The only way I can think to do this is to keep a record of the created `MyApi` inside `MyApiFactory` so the second time `MyApiFactory::create` is called it returns the existing instance. Then I would have to inject `MyApiFactory` into `MyService1` & `MyService2` and call `create` within there constructors or wherever.

This (to me) seems wholly unnecessary and quite unintuitive - is this a problem anyone else has come across? Is there some support for shared services with custom factories in Magento 2 ?

This was more of a question to the Magento 2 developers rather than the community, I did originally create this as an issue but that got shut down, refs: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8182#issuecomment-273763661

Comment: It seems you are using the factory to add config values to the MyApi constructor. Why not inject the Config class into MyApi and get your config values from there? Then you can inject MyApi into other classes' constructor. By default MyApi will be a singleton, unless you define it not to be in your di.xml. In short, skip the factory, the ObjectManager will handle that for you.

Comment: @VincentHornikx there are other things in the factory, I just reduced the code for brevity. In any case injecting only what I need instead of the config service improves my unit testing and also allows for my code to be decoupled from Magento. I consider factories throw away code and in this sense it is okay to couple to Magento in the throw away code. Also `MyApi` is not a singleton in my case, there is an instance per website with different configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you misunderstood the DI logic for Magento 2...

**Factory usage**

```
interface MyApiInterface {
}

class MyApi implements MyApiInterface {
}

class MyService1 {
    public function __construct(MyApiInterfaceFactory $apiFactory) {
        /** @var MyApiInterface $api */
        $api = $apiFactory->create();
    }
}

class MyService2 {
    public function __construct(MyApiInterfaceFactory $apiFactory) {
        /** @var MyApiInterface $api */
        $api = $apiFactory->create();
    }
}
```

Factories will be autogenerated by Magento Framework...

**Singletons**

In your case you want instanciate `MyApi` as a singleton in order to use the same instance in all services. In this case the code should look like following:

```
interface MyApiInterface {
}

class MyApi implements MyApiInterface {
}

class MyService1 {
    public function __construct(MyApiInterface $api) {}
}

class MyService2 {
    public function __construct(MyApiInterface $api) {}
}
```

Just use your `MyApiInterface` as type hint in the constructor and Magento will inject the same instance of `MyApi` each time...

Of course you need to define the preference for your `MyApiInterface` in `di.xml`...

**Own factory**

```
interface MyApiInterface {
}

interface MyApiFactoryInterface {
    public function create(...): MyApiInterface
}

class MyApiFactory implements MyApiFactoryInterface {
}

class MyApi implements MyApiInterface {
}

class MyService1 {
    public function __construct(MyApiFactoryInterface $apiFactory) {
        $api = $apiFactory->create();
    }
}

class MyService2 {
    public function __construct(MyApiFactoryInterface $apiFactory) {
        $api = $apiFactory->create();
    }
}
```

In this case Magento will inject each time the same instance of your factory. So the factory become kind of a singleton...

Comment: Please re-read the question and the comments, this is not what I wanted. I understand about auto-generated factories. I was asking about *custom* factories and whether I can map one to a service as in how other DI frameworks usually work. Also `MyApi` is **not** a singleton and if it was why would I inject a factory which produces the same instance all the time?

Comment: @AydinHassan I understand that your `MyApi` ist not a Singleton - what I mean is that Magento keep all the DI-Instances in a internal storage and use them all the time. If you just use the interface `MyApiInterface` you'll get the same instance each time... If you use the `MyApiInterfaceFactory` you'll get an autogenerated Factory in order to create new instances of `MyApiInterface`. Of course you can use own factories: see update in my previous answer...

Comment: @AydinHassan: Was that answer helpful?

Comment: hey @vadim-justus, sorry no, I already knew this. I wanted to know if there was a way for Magento to execute my *custom* factory when I ask for a service which consumes something created by that factory - for example, how other PHP DI containers work.

Comment: Magen will auto generate the factory only if it does not exists. So you can create your own using the factory interface of Magento and the DI will use your factory instead of auto generate it... I guess...

Comment: Something new here?